# Implementation of simple OOP design with class composition (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, composition

I am looking into **design patterns** and **best practices**, especially on **class composition** ([see my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54475380/6003691)). I have a *specific example* where I found it really hard to implement a good **OOP** design for.

---

### Simple(?) example:

Say there the concept of a garage which holds cars and there is a call to an external service whose response gives information about each car present in a garage.

This is an example response I want to capture and create classes for:

```
[{'carID': '1x148i-36y5-5rt2',
          'carDimensions': {'top': 275,
                            'left': 279,
                            'width': 75,
                            'height': 75},
          'carAttributes': {'weight': {'weightLevel': 'medium',
                                       'value': 1.6},
                            'topSpeed': {'sppedLevel': 'good',
                                      'value': 0.7},
                            'noise': {'noiseLevel': 'low',
                                      'value': 0.32},
                            'accessories': [{'optionsLevel': 'poor',
                                             'quality': 2.8}]}},
  {'carID': '223a3-33e5-4ea3',
          'carDimensions': {'top': 241,
                            'left': 234,
                            'width': 71,
                            'height': 65},
          'carAttributes': {'weight': {'weightLevel': 'light',
                                       'value': 1.1},
                            'topSpeed': {'sppedLevel': 'great',
                                      'value': 1.6},
                            'noise': {'noiseLevel': 'high',
                                      'value': 0.97},
                            'accessories': [{'optionsLevel': 'great',
                                             'quality': 3.2}]}}]
```

Below are my class design approach.

I tried creating a `Car` class that extracts each field like so:

```
class `Car`:

    def __init__(self, car_response_dictionary):
        self.car = car_response_dictionary

    def get_carID(self):
        return self.car.get("carID")

    # etc.
```

and another class to handle some calculations based on the `carDimensions`:

```
class Size:

    def __init__(self, top, left, width, height):
        self.top = top
        self.left = left
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def get_coordinates(self):
        bottom = self.left + self.height
        right = self.top + self.width
        return (self.left, self.top), (bottom, right)
```

and a class to capture the concept of a garage which holds a list of `Car` objects:

```
class Garage:

    def __init__(self, datestamp, cars):
        self.datestamp = datestamp
        self.cars = cars

    # do stuff based on cars
```

So, my idea is to create an instance of a `Garage` and get the response list in `cars`, I try to unpack each car as a `Car` instance object by iterating through the `cars` list of dictionaries and -using class composition- create a `Car` instance for each car.

At this point I find impossible to implement my design in Python and I think that maybe the approach in my design is to be blamed or my poor understanding of class composition.

If someone could provide a simple code implementation for the above example that would be very educational for me. Even if that means that new design is proposed (e.g. I was contemplating of making a `Response` class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are few classes and a 'main' that uses a composition (using the Size class as a data member of Car class).

```
#
# Note that the code does not use 'dict' as an argument for the Car __init__
# but it can be easily modified and use dict as input
#
class Car:
    def __init__(self, id, weight, top_speed, noise, size):
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight
        self.top_speed = top_speed
        self.noise = noise
        self.size = size

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return 'id: {} weight: {} top speed: {}  noise: {} size: {}'.format(self.id, self.weight, self.top_speed,
                                                                        self.noise,
                                                                        self.size)


class Size:
    def __init__(self, top, left, width, height):
        self.top = top
        self.left = left
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def get_coordinates(self):
        bottom = self.left + self.height
        right = self.top + self.width
       return (self.left, self.top), (bottom, right)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[top: {} left: {} width: {} height: {}]'.format(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)


class Garage:
    def __init__(self):
       self.cars_holder = {}

    def add_car(self, car):
        self.cars_holder[car.get_id()] = car

    def remove_car(self, car_id):
        del self.cars_holder[car_id]

    def show_cars(self):
        for car in self.cars_holder.values():
            print(car)


GARAGE_AS_DICT = [{'id': '1x148i-36y5-5rt2',
                   'dimensions': {'top': 275,
                                  'left': 279,
                                  'width': 75,
                                  'height': 75},
                   'attrs': {'weight': 12,
                             'top_speed': 0.7,
                             'noise': 0.45
                             }},
                  {'id': '223a3-33e5-4ea3',
                   'dimensions': {'top': 241,
                                  'left': 234,
                                  'width': 71,
                                  'height': 65},
                   'attrs': {'weight': 12,
                             'top_speed': 0.74,
                             'noise': 0.4345
                             }
                   }]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    garage = Garage()
    for dict_car in GARAGE_AS_DICT:
        attrs = dict_car['attrs']
        dimensions = dict_car['dimensions']
        garage.add_car(Car(dict_car['id'], attrs['weight'], attrs['top_speed'], attrs['noise'],
                       Size(dimensions['top'], dimensions['left'], dimensions['width'], dimensions['height'])))

    garage.show_cars()
```

Output:

```
id: 223a3-33e5-4ea3 weight: 12 top speed: 0.74  noise: 0.4345 size: [top: 241 left: 234 width: 71 height: 65]
id: 1x148i-36y5-5rt2 weight: 12 top speed: 0.7  noise: 0.45 size: [top: 275 left: 279 width: 75 height: 75]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I am confused on how this applies on the given example where the response is a list of dictionaries. I was under the impression that I had to iterate through that list, populate each car, etc. It is at that point that I cannot figure out how the 'Garage' and 'Car' classes fall into place in the implementation. So, if it is not too much trouble, please refactor your answer so that the implementation addresses the provided example cause that is where I struggle to understand. Thanks

Comment: Karim. I have modified the code and now it populates the garage using a list of dicts

Comment: Your `get_id()` method is totally useless - `Car.id` is a public attribute, you don't need an accessor.

Comment: brunu - I agree about the get_id()

Comment: That is a great example, many thanks! Could you please briefly explain the `cars_holder` idea; is it meant to act as the collection of cars? Also, why can't the `Garage` take input in the `__init__` the list of cars - I mean, is that possible but bad practice or not as good as your implementation?

Comment: Karim. The 'cars_holder' holds the car collection. The __init__ could get the cars dict as an input. But I preferred to have the ability to add/remove cars one by one. I hope the code takes you to the right direction.